# Qt widgets not placed correctly

Tags: qt, qwidget, qgridlayout

I've subclassed QWidget and defined constructor this way:

```
LoupingWidget::LoupingWidget(QWidget *parent): QWidget(parent)
{
    QGroupBox *topGroupBox = new QGroupBox(this);

    QGraphicsView *xRGBPlot = new QGraphicsView(this);
    QGraphicsView *yRGBPlot = new QGraphicsView(this);
    QGraphicsView *loupe = new QGraphicsView(this);
    QSlider *slider = new QSlider(this);

    QGridLayout *boxGLayout = new QGridLayout;
    boxGLayout->addWidget(xRGBPlot, 0, 0);
    boxGLayout->addWidget(slider, 0, 1);
    boxGLayout->addWidget(loupe, 1, 0);
    boxGLayout->addWidget(yRGBPlot, 1, 1);

    topGroupBox->setLayout(boxGLayout);
}
```

Next, I am trying to add it in a QDialog:

```
Window::Window(QWidget *parent): QDialog(parent)
{
    LoupingWidget *firstLoupindWidget = new LoupingWidget(this);
    LoupingWidget *secondLoupindWidget = new LoupingWidget(this);
//  QGraphicsView *mainPicture  = new QGraphicsView(this);

    QGridLayout *gridLayout = new QGridLayout;
//    gridLayout->addWidget(mainPicture, 0, 0);
    gridLayout->addWidget(firstLoupindWidget, 1, 0);
    gridLayout->addWidget(secondLoupindWidget, 1, 1);
    setLayout(gridLayout);
}
```

When this two lines are commented out, two widgets are placed horizontally.
And that's good, but when I uncomment lines with another QGraphicsViews, it fills entire window.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LoupingWidget` doesn't have a layout, so when it's added to another layout, layout can't resize it according to its contents. You need to create another layout (e.g. `QGridLayout`) in `LoupingWidget` constructor, add `topGroupBox` to the layout and set the layout as `LoupingWidget`'s layout.